# How to add virtualenv to IBM cloud with Python

Tags: python, ibm-cloud, sentry

I'm trying to add `sentry` to my project to capture errors. To use sentry I need to install `raven` with `pip install raven`.

The problem is when I want to upload it to **IBM** as `ibm function`.

As the docs says I need to upload `.zip` file with all `.py` files that I use including `virtualenv`.

If I do it as follows (including all in virtualenv):

```
zip -r ascrawler.zip venv __main__.py common.py db.py
```

the zip file is bigger than allowed 48MB.

Thus following the tutorial [here](http://jamesthom.as/blog/2017/04/27/python-packages-in-openwhisk/), I can add only those virtualenv packages that I need. Thus I did it as follows:

```
zip -r ascrawler.zip venv/bin/activate_this.py venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/raven venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/raven-6.9.0.dist-info __main__.py common.py db.py
```

But when I try to invoke that function with:

```
ibmcloud wsk action invoke --result ascrawler --param make Audi --param model A3 --param mileage 2500
```

I get an error that `raven` couldn't be found:

```
.....
<module>",
"2018-07-04T12:55:56.590718898Z stderr: from raven import Client", "2018-07-04T12:55:56.590724452Z stderr: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'raven'"
```

Any idea what I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

There are one (small) error stopping this example from working.

- Folder containing virtualenv files must be `virtualenv` and not `venv`.

The Python runtimes [checks for the existance](https://github.com/apache/incubator-openwhisk-runtime-python/blob/master/core/pythonAction/pythonrunner.py#L63) of that directory name to instantiate the user-included modules.